# SQL Server 2005/2008: Insert a File in an varbinary(max) column in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert, blob, varbinary

Is it possible to insert a file in a varbinary(max) column in Transact-SQL? If yes, I would be very please to have a code snippet to at least give me an idea how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

It's so easy - once you know it! :-) Found this on [Greg Duncan's blog](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2007/09/insert-binary-data-into-sql-server-2005.html) a while ago:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(YourVarbinaryColumn)
    SELECT * FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'(name of your file to import)', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import
```

And here's the [MSDN library documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx) on it.

Marc

Comment: remember the path to the file is relative to the SQL server. So if it is C:\test.txt that is on the c: drive of the computer the sql server instance is running on.

Comment: Note that the **AS import** at the end is very important!