# Store binary files with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, image, file, varbinary

I have a small database with a table in Sql Server 2008 and I'm trying to insert some images/videos to it.
Is there any simple way or tool to put images (or any other binary file) in a varbinary field in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio WITHOUT using t-sql queries?

In the past I had used Oracle 11g DB with SQL Developer 3 and in every blob field there was a browse-like button, with it I could load or delete files, also I was able to see the images if I had stored images in those fields.

Thanks,
Kosanag

Comment: In my opinion, and experience, you should store **data** in a database and **files** in a file system. If you are using SQL Server 2008 take a look at the FILESTREAM feature: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: What do you mean, "without using t-sql queries"? Do you expect to right-click a file in Windows explorer, choose copy, and paste it into SQL Server? No, there is no functionality like that built in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload a file to a varbinary with SQL Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053564/upload-a-file-to-a-varbinary-with-sql-management-studio)

Comment: If you'd like to loosen your restrictions and write some T-SQL, you might also be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212494/sql-server-2005-2008-insert-a-file-in-an-varbinarymax-column-in-transact-sql

Comment: @Nathanial Woolls - Thank you for your fast reply, FILESTREAM is indeed a better technique to "put" **files** in a SQL Server DB but it doesn't change the fact that I need to write queries and even worse change them for every file I want to put to my DB.

Comment: So I guess there are only two options either I should write t-sql queries or I should replace management studio with another application, does anyone knows if there is any other decent application that has this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I have found something! There are tools like **SqlLobEditor** that does what microsoft forgot to do about importing/exporting/viewing BLOB data with SQL Server Management Studio. :)